# The function written to the prototype does not wait, and is executed cyclically

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, async-await, prototype

I am trying to add an asynchronous function to the prototype of an object to call it further. Thus:

```js
const ContractObject = Object;

    ContractObject.prototype['getBalance'] = async function(userId: number) {
    const result = await getBalanceTx(userId);
    return result;
  };
```

Internally, I await the result from another function via await. I use it like this:

```js
const result = await myObj.getBalance(25);
```

As a result, two problems arise:

- 1 - Function ReturnTxResult, starts to be called every tick
- 2 - getBalance function does not wait for a response, and is still executed ...

What can you do about it?

P.S By calling the `ReturnTxResult` function separately, everything works fine. Everywhere there is await, all promises are resolved

Comment: You seem to refer to `ContractObject` as a constructor, but also as a plain object. Is that intended? Moreover it is a synonym of `Object`: that really seems wrong. What is the role of `ContractObject` as argument to `ReturnTxResult`? Is there a recursive call to some of these `value.name` properties from within `ReturnTxResult`? There are several unknowns in your code. Please provide enough information so that the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Is this `const ContractObject = Object;` what you actualy have in your code? That seems like a bad idea to add props to internal javascript DataType. To create your own object use `const ContractObject = {};`

Comment: @trincot I used Object later, so that I can refer to the prototype like this without having anything extra inside the object. If there is another way to do this, please let me know. ReturnTxResult returns the result of the transaction given the arguments. ContractObject is a contract object that contains the methods of the contract based on the method. In fact, I just need to nest the methods I need in the object, and pass the necessary parameters there.

Comment: This is all quite vague. Please edit your question so we can reproduce the issue you have.

Comment: @trincot I'm sorry, but the chain of calls / parameters is too long

Comment: @Molda Thanks, but unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: I suggest you make a simplified snippet that still exposes the problem. Surely the long chain of calls that you have now is not all needed to demonstrate the issue. And while you work on such a simplification (just for this question), you may well find out what was causing the issue.

Comment: Are you really doing `const ContractObject = Object;` ??

Comment: What is the result you expect from the promise that `getBalance(25);` returns? Are you really calling `getBalance` or did you mean `this.getBalance`? Or...? Where is the base case of your recursion?

Comment: Please post a complete [mcve] of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why does your function call itself? It looks like you have unbounded recursion to me.

Because it's an async function, your recursion doesn't cause a stack overflow. Instead, as you pointed out, it's called every tick.

Comment: An `async function` that does call itself without an `await` in between actually *will* overflow the stack

Comment: It does not call itself, I'm sorry, I forgot to indicate in the example that it refers to an object